# ERROR - "export 'ɵ9' (imported as 'i64') was not found

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-module

**ERROR in ./src/app/admin/admin.module.ngfactory.js 117:13330-13336
"export 'ɵ9' (imported as 'i64') was not found in './admin-routing.module'**

This is my admin-routing.module file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// Components Imports
import { AdminComponent } from './admin.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './components/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { AdminUsersComponent } from './components/admin-users/admin-users.component';
import { LanguageComponent } from './components/language/language.component';
import { EditLanguageComponent } from './components/language/edit-language/edit-language.component';
import { AddLanguageComponent } from './components/language/add-language/add-language.component';
import { LanguageKeyPairComponent } from './components/language-key-pair/language-key-pair.component';
import { LanguageKeyPairContentComponent } from './components/language-key-pair/language-key-pair-content/language-key-pair-content.component';
import { LanguageKeyPairEditComponent } from './components/language-key-pair/language-key-pair-content/language-key-pair-edit/language-key-pair-edit.component';
import { LanguageKeyPairAddComponent } from './components/language-key-pair/language-key-pair-add/language-key-pair-add.component';
import { RatingQuestionComponent } from './components/rating-question/rating-question.component';
import { AddAdminUserComponent } from './components/admin-users/components/add-admin-user/add-admin-user.component';
import { EditAdminUserComponent } from './components/admin-users/components/edit-admin-user/edit-admin-user.component';
import { PushNotificationComponent } from './components/push-notification/push-notification.component';
import { CancelationPolicyComponent } from './components/cancelation-policy/cancelation-policy.component';
import { PrivacyPolicyComponent } from './components/privacy-policy/privacy-policy.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
// Guard Imports
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { ProvidersAgreementComponent } from './components/providers-agreement/providers-agreement.component';
import { ProviderOnboardingSMSComponent } from './components/provider-onboarding-sms/provider-onboarding-sms.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },

  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: 'client', loadChildren: () => import('./components/client/client.module').then(m => m.ClientModule) },
      { path: 'user', loadChildren: () => import('./components/user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule) },
      { path: 'service-provider', loadChildren: () => import('./components/service-provider/service-provider.module').then(m => m.ServiceProviderModule) },
      { path: 'pricing', loadChildren: () => import('./components/pricing/pricing.module').then(m => m.PricingModule) },
      { path: 'admin-users', component: AdminUsersComponent },
      { path: 'admin-users/edit/:id', component: EditAdminUserComponent },
      { path: 'admin-users/add', component: AddAdminUserComponent },
      { path: 'content', loadChildren: () => import('./components/content/content.module').then(m => m.ContentModule) },
      { path: 'appointment', loadChildren: () => import('./components/appointment/appointment.module').then(m => m.AppointmentModule) },
      { path: 'treatment', loadChildren: () => import('./components/treatment/treatment.module').then(m => m.TreatmentModule) },
      { path: 'pets', loadChildren: () => import('./components/pets/pets.module').then(m => m.PetsModule) },
      { path: 'faq', loadChildren: () => import('./components/faq/faq.module').then(m => m.FaqModule) },
      { path: 'contact-us', loadChildren: () => import('./components/contact-us/contact-us.module').then(m => m.ContactUsModule) },
      { path: 'rating-questions', component: RatingQuestionComponent },
      { path: 'push-notifications', component: PushNotificationComponent },
      { path: 'languages', component: LanguageComponent },
      { path: 'languages/edit/:id', component: EditLanguageComponent },
      { path: 'languages/add', component: AddLanguageComponent },
      { path: 'languages-key', component: LanguageKeyPairComponent },
      { path: 'languages-key/add', component: LanguageKeyPairAddComponent },
      { path: 'languages-key/:id', component: LanguageKeyPairContentComponent },
      { path: 'languages-key/edit/:id', component: LanguageKeyPairEditComponent },
      { path: 'cancelation-policy', component: CancelationPolicyComponent },
      { path: 'privacy-policy', component: PrivacyPolicyComponent },
      { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
      { path: 'providers-agreement', component: ProvidersAgreementComponent },
      { path: 'providers-onboarding-sms', component: ProviderOnboardingSMSComponent }


    ],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }

export const AdminRoutesComponent = [
  DashboardComponent,
  AdminUsersComponent,
  PageNotFoundComponent,
  LanguageComponent,
  EditLanguageComponent,
  AddLanguageComponent,
  LanguageKeyPairComponent,
  LanguageKeyPairContentComponent,
  LanguageKeyPairEditComponent,
  LanguageKeyPairAddComponent,
  RatingQuestionComponent,
  AddAdminUserComponent,
  EditAdminUserComponent,
  PushNotificationComponent,
];
```

This is admin.module file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';

import { AdminRoutingModule } from './admin-routing.module';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';

// NgRx Imports
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { rootReducer } from './store/rootReducer';
import { rootEffect } from './store/rootEffects';

// Theme Imports
import {SharedModule} from './shared/shared.module';
import {
  NgbPopoverModule,
  NgbProgressbarModule,
  NgbTabsetModule,
  NgbButtonsModule,
  NgbDropdownModule,
  NgbTooltipModule
} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { NavigationItem } from './layout/navigation/navigation';

// Guards and Services
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { TokenInterceptorService } from './services/token-interceptor.service';
import { LanguageService } from './services/language.service';
import { LanguageKeyPairService } from './services/language-key-pair.service';
import { AppointmentService } from './services/appointment.service';
import { ClientService } from './services/client.service';
import { TreatmentService } from './services/treatment.service';
import { PetService } from './services/pet.service';
import { FaqService } from './services/faq.service';
import { ServiceProviderService } from './services/service-provider.service';
import { ContentService } from './services/content.service';

import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';

// Components Imports
import { AdminRoutesComponent } from './admin-routing.module';

import { NavigationComponent } from './layout/navigation/navigation.component';
import { NavContentComponent } from './layout/navigation/nav-content/nav-content.component';
import { NavGroupComponent } from './layout/navigation/nav-content/nav-group/nav-group.component';
import { NavCollapseComponent } from './layout/navigation/nav-content/nav-collapse/nav-collapse.component';
import { NavItemComponent } from './layout/navigation/nav-content/nav-item/nav-item.component';
import { NavBarComponent } from './layout/nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
import { NavRightComponent } from './layout/nav-bar/nav-right/nav-right.component';
import { ConfigurationComponent } from './layout/configuration/configuration.component';


import { ToggleFullScreenDirective } from './shared/full-screen/toggle-full-screen';
// Enviornment Import
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { UniquDataPipe } from './pipes/uniqu-data.pipe';
import { CancelationPolicyComponent } from './components/cancelation-policy/cancelation-policy.component';
import { PrivacyPolicyComponent } from './components/privacy-policy/privacy-policy.component';
import { AngularEditorModule } from '@kolkov/angular-editor';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { ProvidersAgreementComponent } from './components/providers-agreement/providers-agreement.component';
import { ProviderOnboardingSMSComponent } from './components/provider-onboarding-sms/provider-onboarding-sms.component';
import {UserModule} from "./components/user/user.module";



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AdminComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    AdminRoutesComponent,

    ConfigurationComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    NavRightComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    NavContentComponent,
    NavCollapseComponent,
    NavGroupComponent,
    NavItemComponent,
    ToggleFullScreenDirective,
    UniquDataPipe,
    CancelationPolicyComponent,
    PrivacyPolicyComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    ProvidersAgreementComponent,
    ProviderOnboardingSMSComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AdminRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AngularEditorModule,
    CKEditorModule,
    // Theme Imports
    SharedModule,
    NgbProgressbarModule,
    NgbPopoverModule,
    NgbTabsetModule,
    NgbButtonsModule,
    NgbDropdownModule,
    UserModule,
    NgbTooltipModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(rootReducer),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 25, // Retains last 25 states
      logOnly: environment.production, // Restrict extension to log-only mode
    }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot(rootEffect)
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    LanguageService,
    LanguageKeyPairService,
    ClientService,
    AppointmentService,
    TreatmentService,
    PetService,
    FaqService,
    ServiceProviderService,
    ContentService,
    AuthGuard,
    {
      provide : HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass : TokenInterceptorService,
      multi : true
    },
    NavigationItem
  ],
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

When i do **ng serve** , it is giving me the error which I mentioned above. Meanwhile, it is important to tell that this error started when I added user componet. I first created user component in admin/component and also I created user module and router module using **ng g m user --routing --flat** in the user component folder. Then, I added its route in admin-routing module.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)